# How to find words beginning with capital letters in string literals in Intellij?

Tags: java, regex, intellij-idea

`[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+`

matches

`fieldWithPath("fruits")`

I was expecting it to only match something like below

`fieldWithPath("FruitasdASSAdaasd")`

Note: I'm using the inbuilt search in Intellij

Comment: use just `[A-Z]+`.

Comment: `[A-Z]+` matches "location" which is weird, for some reason the range of only uppercase letters is also matching lower case letters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you did not check the "case sensitive" option. IDEA is case-insensitive by default.

Comment: Very strange that they modify normal regex behavior with a separate option from enabling regex... definitely not how I would've anticipated that behaving.  Judging from [their documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/tutorial-finding-and-replacing-text-using-regular-expressions.html) it seems like that may be the only change to regex behavior that needs to be toggled separately.